# Passing Optional.absent() values to methods concisely

Tags: java, generics, guava

One problem with using Guava's `Optional` type as arguments of methods is that you can't simply write

```
// method declaration
public void foo(Optional<String> arg);

// compiler error
foo(Optional.absent());
```

due to type inference failing but instead have to add the type explicitly:

```
// real method call
foo(Optional.<String> absent());
```

How can I avoid it?

Comment: There's not really a better way, but FYI, `Optional` tends to be more commonly used as a return value than as a method argument type.  (It's much easier to forget that a return value from a method might be null than an argument to the method you're writing.)

Comment: With a complicated expression, I use a local variable of a proper type (on the RHS of the assignment no type variable is needed) in order to get something more readable. But here nothing can be done until resolution comes (probably JDK8).

Comment: @LouisWasserman There are still benefits to using `Optional` as argument: 1) making it clear to users of API that an argument can be absent; 2) making it easy to pass return value of another method to yours.

Comment: I use the Optional in combination with the Jersey framework. E.g. a @QueryParameter might be not given when the method is called. When I write a unit test however, i need to call using a typed absent Optional

Answer (score -4, accepted):

Just when writing the question, I thought of having

```
public class GuavaConstants {
    @SuppressWarnings( { "raw" })
    public static final Optional ABSENT = Optional.absent();

    // similar for empty ImmutableList, etc.
}
```

and then the call can look like

```
@SuppressWarnings( { "unchecked" })
foo(GuavaConstants.ABSENT);
```

Is there a better approach?

Comment: Yes, `foo(Optional.<String>absent())` is better. This doesn't strike me as something you should be doing at all.

Comment: @ColinD, please post this as an answer, I for one will upvote it right away. The accepted (and only) answer is quite nasty.

Answer (score 8):

If you are dealing with a small set of `Optional<>` types (e.g., mostly strings or a handful of other types), just create some helper methods that bind the type argument for you:

```
public final class AbsentValues {
    public static Optional<String> absentString() {
        return Optional.<String>absent();
    }
}
```

You can even import these statically to result in cleaner code:

```
import static AbsentValues.*;

...

foo(absentString());
```

For less common `Optional<>` types, just specify the type argument explicitly.  It may not be pretty, but it's correct.

Answer (score -1):

So, this is the right way to do this. If not for anything else, let me at least show it here for my own future reference, for everyone who doesn't read questions, like myself :) Thanks to ColinD (and Alexey).

```
foo(Optional.<String>absent())
```