# Conditional operator with Guava's Optional object in Java 7

Tags: java, guava, option-type, conditional-operator

I want to use the conditional operator in Java 7 where the returned object is `com.google.common.base.Optional`, something like this:

```
import com.google.common.base.Optional;
public Optional<String> getFirstElement(String str, String separator) {
    final String[] strs = str.split(separator);
    return strs.length == 0 ? Optional.absent() : Optional.of(strs[0]);
}
```

However, `Optional.absent()` has type `Optional<?>` instead of `Optional<String>`. Any idea about how to solve this?

Comment: Which `Optional` is that?

Comment: relevant: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11757962/passing-optional-absent-values-to-methods-concisely

Comment: Guava `absent` = Java 8 `empty`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

On Java 7, just specify the type explicitly

```
public Optional<String> getFirstElement(String str, String separator) {
    final String[] strs = str.split(separator);
    return strs.length == 0 ? Optional.<String>absent() : Optional.of(strs[0]);
}
```

The [`Optional#absent()`](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git/javadoc/com/google/common/base/Optional.html#absent%28%29) method is generic.

In Java 8, your code will compile fine thanks to some improved type inferrence.